# How to prevent a textarea to insert extra blank spaces?

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea formatted like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control">
  {{ field.value }}
</textarea>
```

This is the result:

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You can do: `<textarea class="form-control">{{ field.value }}</textarea>`. That space is likely from added white space on the first line, along with white space on the left before the value `{{ field.value }}` and potentially more white space after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it without formatting , in one line... textarea takes the spaces which are used in formatting.